# Is it possible to use Angular Material without using CDK?

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, umd, angular-cdk

I'm trying to use Material the old school in ES5 using UMD module definition files.

It was all working fine, until I decided to upgrade to version 5. Now it says that it can't find `bidi` of undefined and as I investigated the issue, I realized that it's because of the new `CDK` or **Component Development Kit**.

Now I can't find a packages CDK UMD file that contains all of its parts in one place, and I really don't want to include all of those a11y, i18n, bidi, etc. one by one.

The question is, the more I look at CDK files, the more I realize that I might not even want them at all. I would be fine without them.

Is there a way to not load them and still use Material?